# How to change font color within a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, colors, datagrid

How can I change the font color (with different colors) of a text within a DataGrid?

Example:

[image]

Comment: there must be a condition to separate blue and rec text what is it? which part should be blue and which should be red?

Comment: You can do that by uing `<Run/>` inside of your `<TextBlock/>`.